# Joining two tables with MySQL for aggregation?

Tags: mysql

I need to join tables to do aggregation. I suck at that. Here's my scenario:

```
CATEGORIES
CatID | CategoryName | Parent
1     | Cars         | NULL
2     | Electronics  | NULL
3     | DVD          | 2
4     | Blu_ray      | 2
5     | Shoes        | NULL
```

So basically, topmost elements don't have parents. Then I have

```
PRODUCTS
ProdID | Prod Name        | CatID
1      | DVD Player 1     | 3
2      | Blu-Ray Player   | 3
3      | Nike             | 5
4      | DVD Player 2     | 3
```

I want to end up with...

```
CATEGORIES
CatID | CategoryName | Parent | totalProds
1     | Cars         | NULL   | 0
2     | Electronics  | NULL   | 0
3     | DVD          | 2      | 2
4     | Blu_ray      | 2      | 1
5     | Shoes        | NULL   | 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you just asking for the total number of products per category?

```
SELECT CatID, CategoryName, Parent, COUNT(*) totalProds
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN products p ON p.CatID = c.CatID
GROUP BY CatId
```

Answer (score 0):

See below query

```
SELECT
    c.`CatID`,
    c.`CategoryName`,
    c.`Parent`,
    COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT p.`ProdID`),0) AS totalProds
FROM `CATEGORIES` c
LEFT JOIN `PRODUCTS` p
ON p.`CatID` = c.`CatID`
ORDER BY c.`CatID`
```

`LEFT JOIN` to return a row for every category.  `COALESCE` to just make sure a 0 is returned if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a limited number of category levels, you can union each level at a time. Here's for 4 levels:

```
SELECT c1.CatID, c1.CategoryName, c1.Parent, COUNT(1) totalProds
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN categories c1 ON c1.CatID = p.CatID
GROUP BY c1.CatID, c1.CategoryName, c1.Parent
UNION
SELECT c2.CatID, c2.CategoryName, c2.Parent, COUNT(1) 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN categories c1 ON c1.CatID = p.CatID
INNER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.CatID = c1.Parent
GROUP BY c2.CatID, c2.CategoryName, c2.Parent
UNION
SELECT c3.CatID, c3.CategoryName, c3.Parent, COUNT(1) 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN categories c1 ON c1.CatID = p.CatID
INNER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.CatID = c1.Parent
INNER JOIN categories c3 ON c3.CatID = c2.Parent
GROUP BY c3.CatID, c3.CategoryName, c3.Parent
UNION
SELECT c4.CatID, c4.CategoryName, c4.Parent, COUNT(1) 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN categories c1 ON c1.CatID = p.CatID
INNER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.CatID = c1.Parent
INNER JOIN categories c3 ON c3.CatID = c2.Parent
INNER JOIN categories c4 ON c4.CatID = c3.Parent
GROUP BY c4.CatID, c4.CategoryName, c4.Parent
```

Hope you get the idea...